# Can a partition be built with 440 x 210 x 50mm 3.6N blocks? and How?

Tags: walls, building-regulations, concrete-block, building, partition

Can a 2.5 metre to ceiling by 2 metre wide internal partition be built with 440 x 210 x 50mm 3.6N block? and How? It will be supported either side onto existing wall and above and below.

How does one lay a partition wall like this? What kind of cement mix, support ect should I use.

This block is a product (not sure if I can mention the name so I won't) - so I assume it must be possible to lay - though through my inexperience it seems difficult to envisage that it will have any strength. Wall strength expectations for a partition would be I suppose, hang a picture, clock, person lean against it ect.

Any advise would be welcome other than just 'it would be better to use 100mm'.

[image: spec]

Comment: What bond are you considering? Flemish?

Comment: @Solar Mike yes Flemish single brick

Comment: Mentioning the product name is fine if asking a question about a specific product. Feel free to [edit] that in. my experience of masonry units of this shape is that they are intended for uses where there is other support, not as freestanding single-brick-thick construction. But perhaps there's a way I don't know of?

Comment: @Ecnerwal I've added some spec. -  product is Thermolite

Comment: http://www.lets-do-diy.com/Projects-and-advice/Brickwork-and-masonry/Building-a-partition-wall-with-concrete-blocks.aspx this is the sort of thing I'm aiming for but at 50mm thickness.

Comment: The only way I could imagine that thickness working without danger of falling down would be with significant vertical reinforcement, and I don't see any provision for that. There isn't enough length to play the "serpentine single-brick wall" trick, (you probably don't want a curved wall) and those are 100mm bricks anyway...